# How do you map regex string replacement values ($1,$2 etc) to a hash?

Tags: regex, perl, hash, dictionary

```
my (@keys,@values) = ($text =~ /\{IS\:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\}(.*)\{\\IS\:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\}/g);
```

is supposed to match strings like this

```
{IS:cow}moo{\IS:cow}
{IS:cow}moo{\IS:cow}    
{IS:dog}bark{\IS:dog}
{IS:dog}meow{\IS:dog} #probably not a dog
```

which works fine, except that all the $1,$2, and $3 value get dumped into @keys .. so I'm trying to figure out how to get these guys into a nice hash of $1 => $2 pairs...

For full context what I'd ***really*** like to do however is have the regex expression return a data structure that looks like (and append a count for the number of times the key was found)

```
{ 
  cow_1 => moo,
  cow_2 => moo,
  dog_1 => bark,
  dog_2 => meow,
}
```

Is there a way to use map{ } function to accomplish this with Regex? Something like this maybe?

```
my %datahash = map { ( $1 eq $3 ) ? { $1 => $2 } : undef } @{ regex...};
```

$1 equals $3 to make sure its a matching tag (no need for recursive checking these tags aren't nested), if so use $1 as the key and $2 as the value;

Then for each of these key => value pairs, i want to replace

```
{IS:cow}moo{\IS:cow}
{IS:cow}moo{\IS:cow}
```

with

```
{cow_1}
{cow_2}
```

then if $cachedData{cow} is true all cow_* will be replaced with their key in %datahash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed useless backslashes and parens from the regex and used shortcuts in the char class:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text = '{IS:cow}moo{\IS:cow}
{IS:cow}moo{\IS:cow}    
{IS:dog}bark{\IS:dog}
{IS:dog}meow{\IS:dog}';

my %cnt;
my %animals;
while ( $text =~ /\{IS:([\w-]+)}(.*)\{\\IS:[\w-]+}/g ){
    $animals{$1 . '_' . ++$cnt{$1}} = $2;
}

print "$_ => $animals{$_}\n" for sort keys %animals;
```

Comment: If you want to ensure the start/end tags match, then do that in the regex with a backref:  /\{IS:([\w-]+)}(.*)\{\\IS:\1}/g

Answer (score 4):

```
$hash{$1} = $2 while 
        $text =~ /\{IS\:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\}
                           (.*)
                  \{\\IS\:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\}/gx;
```

(`/x` modifier added for readability)

Comment: this is great, what does the /x modifier do?

Comment: @nodebunny It ignores whitespace, thus allowing you to format your regex nicely.

Answer (score 1):

- `$dataHash{cow}[$num]` is exactly equivalent to `$dataHash{"cow_$num"}`
- It's easier to get anything that's a cow with $dataHash{cow} as well as, opposed to
  "scanning" the keys with

  ```
  @dataHash{ grep { m/^cow_/ } keys %dataHash }
  ```

  - It also keeps the source data ('cow') separate from the synthetic data ( '1' as this is the first time I've seen this.)

So, I thought it was a good time to bring `multi_hash` into play.

```
sub multi_hash {
    use List::Pairwise qw<mapp>;
    my %h;
    mapp { push @{ $h{ $a } }, $b } @_;
    return wantarray ? %h : \%h;
}
```

With that idiom, you can make a hash, similar to what you want like so:

```
my %dataHash 
    = multi_hash(  map { m/[{]IS:([\w-]+)[}]([^{]+)[{]\\IS:\1[}]/ } @lines )
    ;
```

This gives me:

```
%dataHash: {
             cow => [
                      'moo',
                      'moo'
                    ],
             dog => [
                      'bark',
                      'meow'
                    ]
           }
```